# CRM 13 Notes does not contains only numeric value

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am adding "12345" in the note section on the Lead form.
First it saves and shows us..when i refresh the page it disappears.

It shows that there is a record but that note-record does not display the data("12345").
When we print all the notes by invoking custom code..it prints all the notes with their data...but note record does not show the data on the form if only numeric data is entered.

Is there any feature that is turned off?
or
It is a bug?

Here is the scenario.

First time when I entered note that is "12345"

[image]

After saving the note, i refreshed the form. Note record is not showing data as shown below:

[image]

How this is possible?

Any kind of idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a picture of what you mean? I ask because there is > 1 way of doing notes.

Comment: Hi Keerz,

I have added some images fir more clarification.
Please help.